# R: Ordenar estratos Alluvial plot

Tags: r, ggplot

Estoy intentando ordenar los estratos de un plot alluvial pero no puedo.
Intento darles un nivel pero sigue saliendo la misma escala

```
  dput(ggplot_alluvial_PHQ9)


  structure(list(Var_tiempo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("0 Months Baseline", 
  "3 Months using ETI", "6 Months using ETI", "9 Months using ETI", 
  "12 Months using ETI"), class = "factor"), values = structure(c(1L, 
  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
  1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), levels = c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Moderately severe", 
  "Severe"), class = "factor"), per = c(63.2075471698113, 23.5849056603774, 
  11.3207547169811, 0.943396226415094, 0.943396226415094, 70.1754385964912, 
  22.8070175438597, 3.50877192982456, 3.50877192982456, 69.4736842105263, 
  23.1578947368421, 4.21052631578947, 1.05263157894737, 2.10526315789474, 
  78.6885245901639, 13.1147540983607, 8.19672131147541, 66.6666666666667, 
  24.7311827956989, 7.52688172043011, 1.0752688172043)), row.names = c(NA, 
  -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



  ggplot_alluvial_PHQ9 %>% 
    mutate(values=factor(values,
                   levels = c("Normal",
                              "Mild",
                              "Moderate",
                              "Moderately severe",
                              "Severe")))->ggplot_alluvial_PHQ9


  ggplot(ggplot_alluvial_PHQ9,
   aes(x = Var_tiempo, 
       stratum=paste0(values,sprintf("\n%0.1f",round(per, digits = 1)), "%"),
       # stratum=round(per, digits = 3),
       alluvium = values,
       y = per,
       fill = values, label = values)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, 0)) +
    geom_flow(width = 1/4, aes.flow = "backward") +
    geom_stratum(alpha = .5, width = 1/4, position = "identity") +
    geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),size = 3,discern=FALSE)+
    labs(x="",y="")+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")->plot3;plot3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo ordenarlas?
Gracias de antemano